# Function pointers instead of if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, function-pointers

Does it ever make sense to use function pointers instead of if statements. If the if statement will likely return the same result for most of the programs run?

Is one more efficient than the other?

Example:  If Statement

```
public int getValue()
{
    if(_systemReady == true)
    {
        ...Do Something
        return intResult;
    }
    else
    {
        ...Do Something else
        return intResult;
    }
}

public void systemStateChanged(bool b)
{
    _systemReady = b;
}
```

Could be written something like this: Function pointer

```
private Func<int> _GetValue;

public int getValue()
{
    return _GetValue();
}

public void systemStateChanged(bool b)
{
    _systemReady = b;
    if(_systemReady == true)
    {
         _GetValue = DoSomething;
    }
    else
    {
         GetValue = DoSomethingElse;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See [Eric Lippert's performance rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Performing one branch (which is all that is being done here) is *so blazingly fast* for modern machines it's entirely irrelevant, and is rather assured to not be a bottleneck.

Comment: To the orignial question: Does it ever make sense?   The answer is "yes".  To the implied question: Does it make sense in this case? The answer is "probably not"

Comment: @Servy I am not looking for a performance increase, it just seems like a waste of time to me to be calling a bool which will likely always be true, many thousands of time instead of just when it changes. But as you say in your second comment if it is so fast its pointless even thinking about, so writing if statements probably makes sense as it is somewhat simpler and easier to read.

Comment: @RisingCascade You state that you're worried about evaluating the bool over and over.  If you're not worried about it's affect on performance then what *are* you worried about?  In your question you ask about the efficiency; in context that appears to mean performance.  If that's *not* what you mean then please explain what you *are* looking to improve.

Comment: @Servy I really want to know if one approach is seen to be better than the other. When you have a situation where a value is likely to change very little. Is it common practice to just evaluate a value each time knowing it will likely be the same for most of the program.

Comment: Are `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingElse` going to return the same thing when called repeatedly?  If so, call them once when the boolean changes and store the result.  If not, you're free to use either option; use whichever you and your team finds easiest to read and maintain.